# virtual port operate in atmega MCU, possible?

Tags: c, atmega

For i could not find a entire port in my design but i want my program become uniform(when i change pins i only need change this array), so I want make a virtual port by defined them in a array. When operate I want set each those virtual pins in loop. This just like those macro codes below (of course i can define 2 arrays separately for ports and pins). The length of array(pins) is variable one (maybe 2/3/4 pins) before compile but this is not important.

```
unsigned char bitorder[]={PORTC,6,PORTD,2};
    foreach i,j in (bitorder){
        asm SBI i,j
        // some delay or operation here
        asm CBI i,j
    }
```

If this possible? use function or macro? or pointer to pointer operation?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do here. Are you trying to set up a two dimensional array and then iterate through it? C has no foreach type functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but only by taking an address of the port, as in the following code:

```
#define PINS_COUNT  2
volatile uint8_t *  ports[PINS_COUNT] = {&PORTB, &PORTD};
uint8_t pins[PINS_COUNT] = {1, 2};
int i;
for (i=0; i<PINS_COUNT; i++) {
    *ports[i] |= pins[i];  //
    /* do something */
    *ports[i] &= ~pins[i];
}
```

You could stuff the port pointers and the pins into the same array, but remember that ATmega pointers are 16 bits wide. I am sure there are ways of doing this in assembly as well, but since the question was tagged as "C", I am assuming you are looking for a C solution.